# Program Counter in ARM assembly

Tags: assembly, arm

How is the address from which the value is loaded into r1 register calculated?

```
_start:
    ldrh   r1, [pc, #6]
```

the value of PC = 8054 (address of the ldrh instruction)

According to me, the value of the address should be: PC + 6 = 805A

so it should load the value from address 805A into register, r1.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on whether you're in ARM or Thumb mode.

For ARM mode:

> When using `R15` as the base register you must remember it contains an address 8 bytes on
>   from the address of the current instruction.

For Thumb mode:

> The value of the `PC` will be 4 bytes greater than the address of this instruction, but bit
>   1 of the `PC` is forced to 0 to ensure it is word aligned.

Comment: I am in ARM mode. R15 (or PC), is a 4 byte register in ARM mode, so it contains a 4 byte (32 bit address). Could you tell specific to the assembly language instruction I have mentioned above and the value of PC? PC should be incremented in multiples of 4, I am not sure why 6 is added to it.

Comment: The `PC` is two instructions ahead of the current instruction due to prefetching done by the processor. In ARM mode that means 8 bytes, and in Thumb mode 4 bytes. If the `LDRH` instruction is located at address 0x8054 and you're using an immediate offset of 6 bytes, it would load from address 0x8054+8+6 == 0x8062.

Comment: Thanks. When I am debugging this binary and I check the register contents while at the ldrh instruction, it displays the value of PC register as 0x8054. Why is that so? Just before the execution of the current instruction, the value of PC should have the value = (address of current instruction + 8) right?